# Set mapcontrol's children topmost

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm adding a stackpanel to a mapcontrol. like below

[image]

But some of the points added before are on the top of my stackpanel. How to set my stackpanel topmost?

XAML:

```
<Grid x:Name="gridMain">
        <maps:MapControl
            x:Name="mapControl"
            ZoomInteractionMode="GestureAndControl"
            TiltInteractionMode="GestureAndControl"
            RotateInteractionMode="GestureAndControl">
            <!--ZoomLevel="{x:Bind ViewModel.ZoomLevel, Mode=OneWay}"
            Center="{x:Bind ViewModel.Center, Mode=OneWay}"-->


            <maps:MapItemsControl x:Name="MapItems">
                <maps:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Tapped="MagPoint_Tapped" maps:MapControl.NormalizedAnchorPoint="{Binding NormalizedAnchorPoint}" maps:MapControl.Location="{Binding Location}">
                            <Ellipse Canvas.ZIndex="0" Width="{Binding Mag5}" Height="{Binding Mag5}" Fill="{Binding MagColor}"/>
                            <!--<TextBlock Text="{Binding Mag}"/>-->
                        </Grid>

                    </DataTemplate>
                </maps:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </maps:MapItemsControl>
        </maps:MapControl>
    </Grid>
```

And add panel code.

```
StackPanel sp = new StackPanel();
            sp.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
            sp.CornerRadius = new CornerRadius(15);
            sp.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightGray);
            sp.BorderThickness = new Thickness(1);
            sp.Width = 260;
            sp.MinHeight = 180;
            sp.Padding = new Thickness(10);
            Canvas.SetZIndex(sp, 99999);

mapControl.Children.Add(sp);
            Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Maps.MapControl.SetLocation(sp, new Geopoint(new BasicGeoposition { Longitude = (double)fi.geometry.coordinates[0], Latitude = (double)fi.geometry.coordinates[1] }));
            Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Maps.MapControl.SetNormalizedAnchorPoint(sp, new Point(0.5, 1));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your way of setting the `ZIndex` wouldn't work because the `StackPanel` and the items inside `MapItemsControl` are in different hosts.

With the help of *Live Visual Tree*, you can find out how exactly they get laid out.

[image]

In the screenshot above, the `StackPanel`'s host (i.e. the first `Canvas`) is placed *behind* the `MapOverlayPresenter`s host (i.e. the second `Canvas` where `MapItemsControl` is inserted). So in order to have the `StackPanel` sit above them, you will need to manually set the `ZIndex` of the **first** `Canvas` to `1`.

Once you understand this, the solution becomes simple -

```
Loaded += (s, e) =>
{
    // GetChildByName comes from
    // https://github.com/JustinXinLiu/Continuity/blob/0cc3d7556c747a060d40bae089b80eb845da84fa/Continuity/Extensions/UtilExtensions.cs#L44
    var layerGrid = mapControl.GetChildByName<Grid>("LayerGrid");
    var canvas1 = layerGrid.Children.First();

    Canvas.SetZIndex(canvas1, 1);
};
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, Justin. I found you know everything, haha : )  And I also learned the live visual tree this time.

Comment: Haha thanks I am flattered. :P Yeah LVT is super helpful n I use it all the time!